# How can we safely lock down a Facebook development environment tunneled out to the public internet?

Tags: facebook, ssh

We run a per developer development environment with each developer workstation ssh tunnelled out from our office to the public internet so we can test integration with Facebook canvas apps and facebook callbacks to our urls.

How can we limit access to this environment so Facebook servers can access our servers, cross domain authentication will work for our developers, but no random members of the public can stumble upon our development servers?

Currently the Facebook IP range is unknown, so we don't know where our open graph callbacks are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can **sandbox** your application.

That way only **administrators** & **developers** of the application can interact & see the application.

You can make a change to your Facebook application to sandbox mode going to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

In **Edit settings** page of the current application you choose  **Settings**->**Advanced**->**Sandbox Mode**.

[image]

Comment: That answer helps prevent app discovery and use within Facebook. It does not prevent the code our developers are working on from being available, by necessity, on the public internet. 

Your canvas pages could still easily be found and indexed by Google. Debugging or verbose exception traces a developer might have switched on during the course of development could disclose stack traces or hint at database structures that you don't want to expose.

Comment: You can check for signed_request - this is parameter that only facebook provides to your application. Here is more information: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ That combined with Sandbox mode should provide you with ability facebook to access your applications, but it would not be possible for anyone else outside facebook.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to add a feature to my application to try and stop it leaking information, I would prefer to make sure at the network level that my application can't be accessed at all by anyone but developers AND facebook's servers until it has been deployed to our production environment.